# Haskell Stack doesn't use system Ghc

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use Haskell Stack to setup a project but using the stack provided ghc I am having a -fPIC error
[GitHub issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3203)

To bypass the fPIC problem I'm trying to use a package manager provided GHC using the 7.10.3 version (stack currently is using 8.0.2)

When I try to force stack to use the systm ghc it simply ignores me. 
I've tried to override using /home/user/.stack/config.yaml and {project}/stack.yaml system-ghc : true option... but stack use the 8.0.2 version in the setup.

Am I missing something?

TL;DR

Stack ignore the system-ghc : true option

I'm runnig Sabayon 16

---

"haskell-primer" is the project name

```
stack list-dependencies

base 4.9.1.0
ghc-prim 0.5.0.0
haskell-primer 0.1.0.0
integer-gmp 1.0.0.1
rts 1.0
```

Comment: I think (not sure) that stack will only use system ghc if dependency resolver finds it suitable. Check if one of your dependencies require ghc8.

Comment: thx for the comment.
I've checked with stack list-dependencies

`
stack list-dependencies
base 4.9.1.0
ghc-prim 0.5.0.0
haskell-primer 0.1.0.0
integer-gmp 1.0.0.1
rts 1.0`

Comment: overriding the resolver INTO the stack.yaml seems to work. I edited it to use lts-6.35 and now it map to the system-ghc.

But... I don't know if it's a solution to the problem. I don't want to manually edit all my stack.yaml files...

Comment: Why do you need to use the system GHC? Specify your required `lts` in the `stack.yaml` file and stack will use whatever version of GHC you require. This is the correct way of picking a specific version of GHC for a specific project.

Answer (score 25):

Setting `system-ghc: true` *allows* Stack to use the system GHC if it matches the resolver's constraints. It will not *force* Stack to use the system GHC if it does not match the constraints. If your resolver requires GHC 8 but your system has GHC 7 then Stack will not use your system GHC no matter what value you give `system-ghc`. Conversely, if `system-ghc: false` then Stack will *never* use the system GHC, regardless of whether its version matches.

From the [Stack FAQ](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/faq.md), emphasis mine:

> If you would like stack to use your system GHC installation, use the `--system-ghc` flag or run `stack config set system-ghc --global true` to make stack check your PATH for a suitable GHC by default.
>
> Note that **stack can only use a system GHC installation if its version is compatible with the configuration of the current project, particularly the `resolver` setting**.